# is a race condition for parallel OpenMP threads reading the same shared data possible?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

There is a piece of code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <omp.h>

class DBase
{
public:
  DBase()
  {
    delta=(xmax-xmin)/n;
    for(int i=0; i<n+1; ++i) x.at(i)=xmin+i*delta;
    y={1.0, 3.0, 9.0, 15.0, 20.0, 17.0, 13.0, 9.0, 5.0, 4.0, 1.0};
  }
  double GetXmax(){return xmax;}
  double interpolate(double xx)
  {
    int bin=xx/delta;
    if(bin<0 || bin>n-1) return 0.0;
    double res=y.at(bin)+(y.at(bin+1)-y.at(bin)) * (xx-x.at(bin))
        / (x.at(bin+1) - x.at(bin));
    return res;
  }
private:
  static constexpr int n=10;
  double xmin=0.0;
  double xmax=10.0;
  double delta;
  std::array<double, n+1> x;
  std::array<double, n+1> y;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  DBase dbase;
  const int N=10000;
  std::array<double, N> rnd{0.0};
  std::array<double, N> src{0.0};
  std::array<double, N> res{0.0};
  unsigned seed = 1;
  std::default_random_engine generator (seed);
  for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) rnd.at(i)=
  std::generate_canonical<double,std::numeric_limits<double>::digits>(generator);
#pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
  {
    src.at(i)=rnd.at(i) * dbase.GetXmax();
    res.at(i)=dbase.interpolate(rnd.at(i) * dbase.GetXmax());
  }
  for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) std::cout<<"("<<src.at(i)<<" , "<<res.at(i)
                                  <<") "<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It seemes to work properly with either  **#pragma omp parallel for**

or without it (checked output). But  i can't understand the following things:

1) Different parallel threads access the same arrays x and y of object dbase of class Dbase (i understand that OpenMP implicitly made dbase object shared, i. e. **#pragma omp parallel for shared(dbase)**). Different threads do not write in these arrays, only read. But when they read, can there be a race condition for their reading from x and y or not? If not, how is it organized that at every moment only 1 thread reads from x and y in interpolate() and different threads do not bother each other? Maybe, there is a local copy of dbase object and its x and y arrays in each OpenMP thread (but it is equivalent to **#pragma omp parallel for private(dbase)**)?

2) Shall i write in such code **#pragma omp parallel for shared(dbase)** or **#pragma omp parallel for** is enough?

3) I think that if i placed 1 random number generator inside the for-loop, to make it work properly (not to let its inner state be in race condition), i should write

```
#pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
  {
    src.at(i)=rnd.at(i) * dbase.GetXmax();
  #pragma omp atomic 
    std::generate_canonical<double,std::numeric_limits<double>::digits> 
    (generator)
    res.at(i)=dbase.interpolate(rnd.at(i) * dbase.GetXmax());
  }
```

The **#pragma omp atomic** would destroy the increase in performance (would make threads wait) from **#pragma omp parallel for**. So, the only correct way how to use random numbers inside a parallel region is to have own generator (or seed) for each thread or prepare all needed random numbers before the for-loop. Is it correct?

Comment: "But when they read, can there be a race condition" - *Race condition* by **definition** implies writing. If there is no write, then there is no race condition.

Comment: There is 1 book and 10 people who want to read it. They have to read it one by one (1 is reading, all the other 9 are waiting, similar to a mutex in c++). As i understand, the situation with OpenMP threads and 1 shared data block between them is similar. More than 1 thread can not access the shared data at a moment of time time, isn't it (or several threads can be reading the same data at the same moment)? If it is true, than how do the threads not disturb each other while accessing the shared data, how is it organized that at every moment only 1 thread is reading data? Thank You.

Comment: "how do the threads not disturb each other while accessing the shared data" - Again, there is no problem in reading shared data from the several threads.

Comment: So, for example, 256 OpenMP threads can be reading the same shared data (for example, array) at the same moment, and there is no problem?

Comment: @And How about people can read the same book if they're sit next to each other? All processors can read the same memory address at 'the same time' if they have a copy in their local cache. You might want to look about cache coherence.

Comment: So, before all the processors of CPU will be reading the same shared data, they make a copy of the data in their local cache. That is why they do not bother each other while reading the same shared data. Did i understand right?

Comment: I wanted to mean "cores of CPU".